# Flexible Flexbox Grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm looking for a way to make this kind of dynamic flexbox grid:

Even amount of items: Standard 2 column Grid

Uneven amount of items: The last item should use two rows on the right column

(exception: if only two items available )

[image: See the attached image:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to create your *2 column grid* using `flexbox`es:

Check out the code below:

```js
$('input[type=button]').click(function() {
  $('.wrapper').append('<div></div>');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.wrapper > div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 0 1 50%;
  height: 100px;
}
.wrapper > div:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(even) {
  height: 200px;
}
.wrapper > div:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(even) + div {
  margin-top: -100px;
}
input[type=button] {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
.wrapper > div:nth-last-child(2):first-child {
  height: 200px;
}
.wrapper > div:nth-last-child(2):first-child + div {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Add Element" />
```

This is actually a *hack* that adjusts for `height` and `margin` of the boxes.

Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

Comment: @fabuchao made some edits to adjust the height for the `2 items` case... check it out and let me know your thoughts...

Comment: Excactly what I was looking for. Thank you for that!!! Works perfectly