# Determine layout based on flex children count?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

Is there a way to determine layouts with css/html based on the specific child amounts?

See below for a layout example.

I've attempted to get it to work with nth-child, but I may be doing this incorrectly..

https://codepen.io/brycesnyder/pen/EvBzWq

But I'm not sure if there is a way to make all elements span 50% width, and if there are more than 1 the following should stack.

```
/* three items */
li:first-child:nth-last-child(3):not(:first-child),
li:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ li {
    background: green;
}
```

[image]

EDIT: I know this is possible via standard elements like so: https://codepen.io/brycesnyder/pen/GvbbyY I want to be able to use just a UL > LI

Comment: something like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39386259/flexible-flexbox-grid)?

Comment: @kukkuz this definitely helps! I didnt add the correct layout visuals, so for anything 4 + I'd like it to keep to the right but keep spanning within that area.. if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

So... it's not exactly "based on the number of children", but you can achieve the layout you're looking for by changing your flex direction to column, setting width to 50%, and having the first element have flex; 0 0 100%.  You'll also need to set the special case of a 1 child list (:first-child:nth-last-child(1)) to be width 100%.

The key css ends up looking like this:

```
ul {
padding:10px 1px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 200px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    outline:1px solid gray;
    text-align:center;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

li:first-child {
    height: 100%;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
}

/* one item */
li:first-child:nth-last-child(1) {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here's a codepen I set up forked from yours:

https://codepen.io/kball/pen/yomyyg